# I insert new parent row and child rowstate changes from Added to unchanged

Tags: sql, vb.net, tableadapter

rowsUpdated is an int32 to count how many rows are updated

```
rowsToUpdate = dataset.ParentTable.Select("", "", dataviewRowState.Added)

if rowsToUpdate isNot Nothing then

for each row as datarow in RowsToUpdate

    **changes the rowstate:** 
    rowsUpdated = rowsUpdated + ParentTableAdapter.update(row)

 Next row

End if
```

I'm sure it's something I'm over looking but I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance,
Joel

Comment: Can you be more specific about what behavior you are seeing and what behavior you expect?

Comment: what I'm expecting is, when the program passes the parentTableAdapter.update(row) line, for the child row's rowstate to remain "Added". 
What I'm seeing though is when my program passes that line the child row's rowstate change to Unchanged.

Comment: i can´t see where are you performing anything with childrows or checking it

when you call update from a tableadapter, at the and, it performs an accept changes which switches the rowstates to unchanged

Comment: that's what's throwing me off, I was looking at both the parent and child's rowstate, at this point I haven't touched the child row. Though, when I insert the parent row I notice that both child and parent rowstates go from added to unchanged

Comment: ok, got it working, What I ended up doing was going into the dataset and completely deleting and reinserting the child table and reconnecting the relation and the stored procedures associated to the child table. Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

set the relation's accept/reject rule in dataSet designer to none